# Mysql make specific row to appear at the bottom of the results

Tags: mysql

I have a specific requirement where a specific row with a certain name value to appear at the bottom of the results instead of following the normal ordering.

To keep this simple assume the following

```
SELECT * FROM GROCERY ORDER BY itemId;
```

Current Result

```
+------------+------------+
|  itemName  |   ItemId   |
+------------+------------+
| Banana     |  0111111   |
| Carrot     |  0222222   |
| Mango      |  0333333   |   
| Orange     |  0444444   |
+------------+------------+
```

What Im trying to get move carrot to the end of the results

```
+------------+------------+
|  itemName  |   ItemId   |
+------------+------------+
| Banana     |  0111111   |
| Mango      |  0333333   |   
| Orange     |  0444444   |
| Carrot     |  0222222   |
+------------+------------+
```

The actual code is more complex and im doing this since this results are used to show a paginated result set. Hard coding this would be bad practice(Which is going to make a lot of issues else where).Rest of the result set need to follow the normal ordering.

Is this possible from mysql is so how.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY IF(ItemName = 'Carrot', 1, 0),
         ItemName
```

Comment: This solution works as expected.Please add the correction.Ill mark as answered

Comment: @ShalithaVikum In the OP stands `ORDER BY itemId`. So, is it `ItemName` or `ItemId` ?

Comment: i think `ORDER BY IF(ItemId = 'Carrot', 1, 0)` need to be corrected as `ORDER BY IF(itemName = 'Carrot', 1, 0)` that worked for me.

Comment: @ShalithaVikum I've updated my question, but you should correct the headers of the tables in OP accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting it into 2 SQL statements and add rows by using UNION.

Select * from GROCERY where itemid not in ('02222222')
Union
Select * from GROCERY where itemid in ('02222222')